# file_exists() versus in_array() of scandir() -- which is faster?

Tags: php

Let's say we have a loop like this:

```
foreach($entries as $entry){ // let's say this loops 1000 times
   if (file_exists('/some/dir/'.$entry.'.jpg')){
      echo 'file exists';
   }
}
```

I assume this has to access the HDD 1000 times and check if each file exists.

What about doing this instead?

```
$files = scandir('/some/dir/');
foreach($entries as $entry){ // let's say this loops 1000 times
   if (in_array($entry.'.jpg', $files)){
      echo 'file exists';
   }
}
```

**Question 1:** If this accesses the HDD once, then I believe it should be a lot faster. Am I right on this one?

However, what if I have to check sub-directories for a file, like this:

```
foreach($entries as $entry){ // let's say this loops 1000 times
   if (file_exists('/some/dir/'.$entry['id'].'/'.$entry['name'].'.jpg')){
      echo 'file exists';
   }
}
```

**Question 2:** If I want to apply the above technique (files in array) to check if the entries exist, how can I `scandir()` sub-directories into the array, so that I can compare the file existence using this method?

Comment: *I assume this has to access the HDD 1000 times and check if each file exists.* -> If you don't have a cache...

Comment: file_exists() is known to be rather slow. But what are you trying to develop exactly? Most of the time it's not a speed issue, but coding errors.

Comment: You can speed up `in_array()` by doing `array_flip()` first and then use `isset()` instead.

Comment: Your question doesn't have a definitive answer; do you need to scan the folder many times? does it still matter when you cache it? how is `$entries` populated? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im my opinion, I believe the `scandir()` will be faster as it only reads the directory once, in addition `file_exists()` is known to be quite slow.

Furthermore, you could use `glob()`. This will list all files in a directory that match a particular pattern. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Regardless of my opinion, you can run a simple script like so to test the speed:

```
<?php

// Get the start time
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Do the glob() method here

// Get the finish time
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo '\'glob()\' finished in ' . $time . 'seconds';

// Do the file_exists() method here

// Get the finish time
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo '\'file_exists()\' finished in ' . $time . 'seconds';

// Do the scandir() method here

// Get the finish time
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo '\'scandir()\' finished in ' . $time . 'seconds';

?>
```

***Not sure how the above script will behave with the cache, you may have to separate the tests into separate files and run individually***

### Update 1

You could also implement the function `memory_get_usage()` to return the amount of memory currently allocated to the PHP script. You may find this useful. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) for more details.

### Update 2

As for your second question, there are several ways you can list all files in a directory, including sub-directories. See the answers to this question:

[Scan files in a directory and sub-directory and store their path in array using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870731/scan-files-in-a-directory-and-sub-directory-and-store-their-path-in-array-using)

Comment: And use memory_get_usage get the memory amount in bytes.

Comment: @likai Yes that could also be useful +1, I will amend my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script).

I modified the "question code" such as, you can do a fast check by,

```
<?php
   $start = microtime();
    //Your code
    $end = microtime();
    $result= $now-$then;
    echo $result;
?>
```

Personally i think `scandir()` will be faster than `in_array()`.