# Image files in directory

Tags: php

firstly I'd like to tell you that I know there are some answers already for this problem, but I don't know PHP, so I'd be really glad if you could help me.

So I have my website directory divided like that

1. css
2. images

   1. abandonedhotel
   2. katka
3. js
4. php

Well, what I'd like to know if there's possibility for .php file in "php" folter to access the "images" folder and subfolders and count the .jpg files there. Also if there could be some exclusion for "title.jpg" because I don't need that to count in. Also if is it possible to list those .jpg files (again without title.jgp) that'd be cool.

Thanks in advance to anybody who helps me.

Comment: Yes, there are possibilities for all your questions.

Comment: Take a look at phps `glob()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something around the lines of:

```
<?php

function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
}

function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
    $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
    $fileList = array();
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
    }
    return $fileList;
}

$count = 0;
foreach(rsearch("../images/", "_.*jpg_iU") as $file) {
  if(!endsWith($file, "title.jpg")) {
    $count++;
    // output $file
  }
}

?>
```

-> [php glob - scan in subfolders for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file)

-> [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the effort man, I wouldn't be able do it myself. However, I get this error and I don't know how to solve it. [ERROR](http://i.imgur.com/eNLXtRx.png)

Comment: Do you have php5? Otherwise you have to use the other function mentioned in my link.

Comment: Yes, 5.5.12 exactly.

Comment: Updated my answer. You have to make sure that the folder exists relative to your php script. Otherwise you an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hope I didn't bother you much.