# PHP: Get all zip file from multiple sub-directories using scandir

Tags: php, arrays

I have a folder store_files under that I have multiple sub-folders. Now I can get all folders and all the files. Now I want to get all folders and nothing else but zip files. I try to add condition that if file extension is equal to zip but seems not working. If I add the $ext == 'zip' nothing show in the output. Is there another way to get specific file like for example in images there's a `glob($getDirectory. '*.zip')`

```
                function listFolderFiles($dir){
                    $ffs = scandir($dir);
                    echo '<ol>';
                    foreach($ffs as $ff){
                        $ext = pathinfo($ff, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && $ext == 'zip'){
                            echo '<li>';
                            $str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $ff);
                            $str = substr($str, 0,-1);

                            $getYear = substr($str, 0,4);
                            $getMonth = substr($str, -4,2);
                            $getDay = substr($str, -2,2);
                            $theDate = $getYear.'-'.$getMonth.'-'.$getDay;
                            $theRealDate = date('Y M j', strtotime($theDate));
                            echo $theRealDate;


                            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                             listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                            }

                            echo '</li>';
                        }

                    }
                    echo '</ol>';
                }
                listFolderFiles('store_files');
```

Comment: Why don't you use `glob()`?

Comment: Not directly, `glob()` does not work recursively. But you can very easily build a wrapper around it. Take a look at that answer, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file

Comment: @arkascha or simply by using spl iterators

Comment: Certainly `glob()` does not work recursively by itself. But one can easily build recursive wrapper as a 2 liner around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem stems from the fact that `scandir()` isn't (by itself) a recursive directory search, it only lists the files and directories directly in the specified directory.  You have accounted for that already with your recursive call to your `listFolderFiles()` function if you detect that `$ff` is a directory.  However, your problem is that you have already filtered out directories in your previous if statement (assuming your directories don't end in '.zip').  I think the below function is what you are after:

```
            function listFolderFiles($dir){
                $ffs = scandir($dir);
                echo '<ol>';
                foreach($ffs as $ff){
                    $ext = pathinfo($ff, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && (is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff) || $ext == 'zip')){
                        echo '<li>';
                        $str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $ff);
                        $str = substr($str, 0,-1);

                        $getYear = substr($str, 0,4);
                        $getMonth = substr($str, -4,2);
                        $getDay = substr($str, -2,2);
                        $theDate = $getYear.'-'.$getMonth.'-'.$getDay;
                        $theRealDate = date('Y M j', strtotime($theDate));
                        echo $theRealDate;


                        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                         listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                        }

                        echo '</li>';
                    }

                }
                echo '</ol>';
            }
            listFolderFiles('store_files');
```

Comment: Thanks really helpful I actually did, but this more cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using [glob](http://php.net/glob) will be appropriate for this context:

```
$ffs = glob($dir . "/*/*.zip");
```

will only get zip files from the sub-directories and not the parent directory .

you may need to use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) , this will be more appropriate

```
$files = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($files, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if (false === strpos($file, '/.') && strpos($file, '.zip')) {
        echo $file, "\n";
    }
}
```

thanks goes to [this comment submitter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#92710).