# Replace if key is in a text

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a emoji system using php for my website comment earea. I have created the table for emoji list. Like this:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| emoji_id |  emoji_key |  emoji_img  |
+----------+------------+-------------+
|    1     |   :smile:  |  smile.png  |
+----------+------------+-------------+
|    2     |   :heart:  |  heart.png  |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

So for example user posted a comment like this:

Hi this is a first comment i `:heart:` this comment `:smile:` .

I want to detect the text for emoji. If emoji_key is exist in the comment then replace the :heart: to heart.png .

`<img src="emoji/<?php echo $emoji_img;?>" />`

is there anyway to do this ?

For example:

`$userComment = 'Hi this is a first comment i :heart: this comment :smile: .';`
 Pring should like this:

```
Hi this is my first comment <img src="emoji/heart.png"> this comment <img src="emoji/smile.png">
```

Comment: You really have two question baked in here.  The first question is about how to retrieve information from your MySQL database.  The second question is how can do a regex or other type of text replacement, to generate the output you want.

Comment: Do you try to use `str_replace` for example? It's really easy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using mysqli and your connection is called `$conn`. First, you need to find the emoji strings in your user comment, which you can do with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/(:\w+:)/', $userComment, $matches);
```

Now you can search for those strings in your emoji table (I'm assuming it's called `emojis`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM emojis WHERE emoji_key IN ('" . implode("','", $matches[1]) . "')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Now go through the results and replace the values in your string using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userComment = str_replace($row['emoji_key'], "<img src=\"emoji/{$row['emoji_img']}\">", $userComment);
}
echo $userComment;
```

Output:

```
Hi this is a first comment i <img src="emoji/heart.png"> this comment <img src="emoji/smile.png"> .
```

Comment: This is more complicated than it has to be. Just load all Emojis from the table and str_replace them.

Comment: @Fitzi I did consider that but if there are hundreds or more (of emojis) and there are a lot of comments to process it could be slow.

Comment: Assuming there are not going to be more than a few hundred emojis, the preg_match_all may be equally slow. And if there are a lot of comments to process it's faster to load all emojis once, since you probably need most of them anyway.

Comment: @Fitzi a few hundred in total, only a few in any given comment. But yes, if I was processing a lot of comments I would find all the emojis first, read them all from the table in one operation and then process all the comments. Dependent on emoji usage it might well be more efficient to just read them all. That's something that only OP can determine.

Comment: @Nick Your answer is working fine but i have one question if you have a time please answer me. I am using this code for removing br tags and something else : `function htmlcode($orimessage) { 
// convert to unix new lines 
$message = preg_replace('/\\\\[nr]/', '<br>',  
htmlspecialchars($orimessage, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));  
return  preg_replace('~(?:<br\s*/?\s*>\s*)+~', '<br>', $message);  
}` and echo is like this `echo htmlcode($userComment);`  My code does not allow to use your answer. There is a solution about it ?

Comment: @Azzo can't you just do the replace of emoji strings after you call `htmlcode`?

Comment: @Nick Yes it is not showing image it is just showing a text like this: `Hi this is a first comment i <img src="emoji/heart.png"> this comment <img src="emoji/smile.png">` . The image is not showing only url text is on there.

Comment: @Azzo that's because of your call to `htmlspecialchars` which is escaping the tag characters (`<` and `>`). That's why I suggested you call your `htmlcode` function **before** any of this code.

Comment: @Azzo `echo $Dot->Dot_Smile(htmlcode($UserCommentText,$base_url));` should be `echo $Dot->Dot_Smile(htmlcode($UserCommentText),$base_url);` but otherwise that looks like it should work

Comment: @Nick Thank you so much for your answer. You teach me something. I wish they hadn't given a negative score.

Comment: @Nick It is not working more than one key. Just showing one smiley image second is just like this :fast_happy:

Comment: Are you sure there's an entry for `:fast_happy:` in your table?

Comment: @Nick Yes i am sure comment looks like this: `Hi bro. How are you :fast_fire: your home is ready now :fast_happy:` and :fast_happy: is not image

Comment: @Nick Please look at this screenshot  https://prnt.sc/lnkxcd . I have try to comment like this: `Here is :fast_heart: and here is :fast_angry:` and angry is looks like image but heart not is image it is just a text.

Comment: @Nick I think it's just displaying the sorting priority. Because `:fast_angry:` is id 1 `:fast_heart:` id is 2

Comment: @Nick Here is comment looks like screen shot link : https://prnt.sc/lnl0z5

Comment: @Azzo I can't say what that problem is. Here's an example of the code https://3v4l.org/uHg7A and the query that it generates https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dce2281312e0303d68a61f5e56a88b7e all working fine with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This May Help...
Try to modify it as per your requirements...

```
$userComment = 'Hi this is a first comment i :heart: this comment :smile: .';
preg_match_all('/:(.*?)\:/s', $userComment, $m);

$newComment = str_replace($m[0], ' <img src="emoji/'.$m[1].'.png">', $userComment );

echo $newComment;
```