# How to properly show all files in directory and sub directory via php

Tags: php

I have 4 folders that I want to check the images and php files in it.
here is the structural folder arrangement.

The **main_folder** contains two sub-folder **(second_folder and third_folder)** while the **third_folder** contains a sub-folder **(fourth_folder)** and so on.

Currently with the code below, I can only access all the files in **first_main_folder**.

```
$files = glob('first_Main_folder/*.{jpg,png,gif,php}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
echo "<br>$file<br>";
}
```

Please how do I access
files in the remaining subfolders **(second_folder, third_folder, fourth_folder)** and so on

Thanks

```
first_Main_folder
test.png
data.php
check.gif


    second_folder
    tony.jpg
    mark.gif
    action.php

    third_folder
    index.php
    post.php
    sender.php
    han.gif

        fourth_folder
            catch.php
            index2.php
            redirect.php

       and so on
```

Comment: This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17161106/369143).

Comment: @Bram Verstraten can you please illustrate with example using my directory. no file is showed on my own end after glob scanning

Comment: please find my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file/17161106#17161106).

```
function rsearch($folder, $pattern='/.*/') {
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

    $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
    $fileList = array();

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
    }
    return $fileList;
}


$result = rsearch('./');
print_r($result);
```

Comment: My solution already answered the question but it seems your own solution is also good so am accepting as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This function below scan both main and all sub-directory to the very end. It works for me. thanks.

```
function outputFiles1($path){
    // Check directory exists or not
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        // Search the files in this directory
        $files = glob($path ."/*");
        if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo basename($file) . filesize($file) . "<br>";
                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    outputFiles1("$file");
                }
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

// Call the function
outputFiles1("C:/xampp/htdocs/first_main_folder");
```