# search for files with established criteria php

Tags: php, glob

as the title suggests, I would like to create a file search system with criteria.
I would like to filter the file name whether it contains a specific sequence of numbers or letters.

example:

CRITERIA WITH WHICH I WOULD FILTER THE RESEARCH

value 1 = FRGHSD02D5102T
value 2 = 005878

[file]
00256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT I WANT TO FIND IT

FRGHSD02D5102T00256_0013005878.TXT I WANT TO FIND IT

_FRGHSD02D5102T001300587800256.TXT I WANT TO FIND IT

00058_GHT52DSF56S03U0014002545.TXT I DO NOT WANT TO FIND IT

I tried to get this using the glob () function;

```
$ files = glob ("... / ..... / *. txt");
```

so he finds nothing

```
$ files = glob ("... / ..... / *. txt / * {002} * {001} *. txt");
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php glob - scan in subfolders for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file)

Comment: this is not the main question!  eliminate the final part

Comment: I added an answer, would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax can be used:

`^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878).+$`

This would match any line that contains `FRGHSD02D5102T` or `005878`:

```
00256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT ✅
FRGHSD02D5102T00256_0013005878.TXT ✅
_FRGHSD02D5102T001300587800256.TXT ✅
00256_005878.TXT ✅
FRGHSD02D5102T.TXT ✅
00058_GHT52DSF56S03U0014002545.TXT ❌
00256_005873.TXT ❌
```

This can be combined with glob to search through all folders and subfolders for the specific pattern:

```
$folder = __DIR__ . '/data';
$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878).+$/';

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
$ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($files as $file) {
    echo 'found matching file: ' . $file[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

the folder structure:

```
data
|-- 00256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT
|-- example.TXT
`-- test
    `-- YES256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT
```

the result:

```
found matching file: /Users/stackoverflow/dev/data/00256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT
found matching file: /Users/stackoverflow/dev/data/test/YES256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT
```

When searching for an specific extension the following snippet can be used:

> .pdf

```
$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001|002).*\.pdf$/';
```

> .txt

```
$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001|002).*\.TXT$/';
```

> .pdf, .PDF, .PdFm, contains 001 and 002 OR 002 and 001

```
$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001.*002|002.*001).*\.pdf/i';
```

matches:

```
data
|-- 00256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT ❌
|-- example.TXT ❌
|-- hell001hello.pdf ❌
|-- hell001hello002.pdf ✅
|-- hell002hello001.pdf ✅
`-- test
    `-- YES256_FRGHSD02D5102T0013005878.TXT ❌
```

The `/i` makes it case-insensitive so it will match any casing of `PDF`.

The `\.` escapes the `.` because we need to match the literal `.` instead of matching all characters.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can I use this syntax in glob ()?

$files = glob ("... / ..... / .*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878).+$. txt");

Comment: Why are there so many dots? Do they represent an absolute path or is it navigating up the tree? @fraielito

Comment: actually my goal would be to search in a folder that contains other folders (I don't know the actual number of folders)

Comment: For searching in nested folders the following may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file @fraielito

Comment: I added example code for searching using `glob` @fraielito

Comment: thank you so much. you have been really useful. as soon as I have a moment I try it.

Comment: the search under the folders works perfectly, but I have problems with searching for files. in the example you mentioned do not put the file exam I need to find. I tried: /^.*(001|002).+$.txt/ but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you give an example file name it should match? Should they always end with `.TXT`? @fraielito

Comment: exactly the file always ends with a fixed extension.  eg hell001hello002.pdf or 002hello001.pdf etc.

Comment: You can add the options to: `$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878).+$/';` such as: `$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001|002).+$/';` @fraielito

Comment: sorry I didn't express myself well.  I wanted to know how to add the extension to the file.  in this example 
$pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001|002).+$/' to search for PDF files I add $ pattern = '/^.*(FRGHSD02D5102T|005878|001|002).+$  .  PDF/ ';

correct?

Comment: Added example for extensions for PDF and text. @fraielito

Comment: You should replace `…|002).+\.TXT$` by `…|002).*\.TXT$` (`+` replaced by `*`), otherwise you require at least one character between the matched sequence and the extension.

Comment: Did the provided examples help? @fraielito

Comment: This syntax works correctly
$ pattern = '/^.*(001|002).*\.txt$/';
but it distinguishes between .TXT and .txt.
In this case it only finds the .txt file and not .TXT.

Then find both the file containing 001 002 but also the file that contains only one of the two values ​​(eg 001), I would like to find only the file that contains both the value 1 (001) and the value 2 (002) .

Comment: this should do what I say

$ pattern = '/^.*(001).*(002).*(\.txt|\.TXT)$/';

Correct?

Comment: Does the `/i` fix the casing issue? @fraielito

Comment: Glad to hear! Could you mark the provided answer as solution so others can find it? @fraielito

Comment: Tick the checkmark under the up/downvote arrows, guide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 @fraielito

Comment: @MaartenDev Sorry if placed in this discussion.  You can search with glob in a network folder.
 I have a network unit (WITH SPACES):
 //DATA/FOLDER/FOLDER TWO/

Comment: Why did un-accept the solution, it solves the original problem you stated. Please mark it as answer again and ask your a new question instead of changing this one. @fraielito

Comment: sorry I accidentally clicked. I can't make a new application with my account now.

Comment: No worries, what part fails when using an external disk? Does it fail matching the file names? It seems to work: https://regexr.com/4m0aa @fraielito

Comment: sorry as not said.  I missed the path.  Thanks again.  it works properly: //DATA/FOLDER TWO